# cannot add bootstrap popover from javascript to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I am using javascript to generate an array of cards in HTML dynamically and currently, I am putting in each card button when the user clicks on this button he should be able to see the popover, but before that, I fetch some data to put on the cards, but something is wrong or missing, the popover doesn't appear, and if I commented the first line of loadPhotos() it works correctly.

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

const getAllPhotos = async () => {
    let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos').then(
        response => { return response.json() }
    )
    return res;
}

const displayPhotos = (photos) => {
    const view = document.getElementById('photosGrid');
    photos.forEach(element => {
        view.append(element)

    });
}
const createCard = (data) => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card', 'col-lg-2', 'm-2', 'p-0')
    const optionsButton = document.createElement('button')
    optionsButton.innerText = "test"
    optionsButton.title = "title of me"
    optionsButton.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'popover')
    optionsButton.setAttribute('data-content', 'content of me')
    card.appendChild(optionsButton)
    return card;
}
const createCardsArray = async (data) => {
    const res = await data.map(d => {
        return createCard(d);
    })
    return res;
}
const loadPhotos = async () => {
    const photos = await getAllPhotos();
    const cards = await createCardsArray([1, 2]);
    displayPhotos(cards);
}

loadPhotos();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Pinterest Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="photosGrid">

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize the popover after creating the elements, if more elements are added later, you can reinitialize the popover.

JQuery is adding the popover to the elements during initialization, thus elements created after initialization are not assigned their popups by JQuery